# Fail to redefine enumerate when babel used

Tags: enumerate, babel

I wish to redefine the `enumerate` environment to have a continuous numbering through the different lists. I managed to do this, but my solution fails when using the babel package. Here is my ECM: it's OK when the babel line is commented.

May anyone explain me what's wrong with this package? Thanks a lot.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[frenchb]{babel}

\def\nbq{0}
\let\oldenumerate\enumerate
\let\oldendenumerate\endenumerate
\renewenvironment{enumerate}{\oldenumerate\setcounter{enumi}{\nbq}}{\xdef\nbq{\theenumi}\oldendenumerate}

\begin{document}

\begin{enumerate}
\item \nbq
\item \nbq
\end{enumerate}

\begin{enumerate}
\item \nbq
\item \nbq
\end{enumerate}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 2):

`babel` gets in the way because the French module redefines lists *after* your redefinition.

In my opinion it's better to use a different method based on `enumitem`:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[frenchb]{babel}

\usepackage{enumitem}
\newlist{contenum}{enumerate}{1}
\setlist[contenum]{label=\arabic*.,resume}

\begin{document}

\begin{contenum}
\item Item
\item Item
\end{contenum}
Break between the lists
\begin{contenum}
\item Item
\item Item
\end{contenum}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Since egreg already stated (he was just quicker than me) that `babel-french` does redefinitions to the `lists` provided by `LaTeX` it's necessary to do the own redefinitions after `babel` came into action, i.e. add it either in the document body or use the `\AtBeginDocument{...}` hook, which is processed consecutively, i.e. the `babel` redefinitions are done already, the new ones can come into action.

However, the `enumitem` - way with the `resume` option is easier, of course.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[frenchb]{babel}

\def\nbq{0}
\AtBeginDocument{%
  \let\oldenumerate\enumerate
  \let\oldendenumerate\endenumerate
  \renewenvironment{enumerate}{%
    \oldenumerate\setcounter{enumi}{\nbq}
  }{%
    \xdef\nbq{\number\value{enumi}}
    \oldendenumerate
  }
}
\begin{document}

\begin{enumerate}
\item \nbq
\item \nbq
\end{enumerate}

\begin{enumerate}
\item \nbq
\item \nbq
\end{enumerate}

\end{document}
```

[image]